# Trouble wiring a Leviton DZ15S (originally a single pole with two black?)

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan, home-automation

I'm trying to replace an old single pole toggle switch with a new Leviton DZ15S.

Here's the issue... The new Leviton requires 3 connections to function. Black, red, and white.

Please see the following diagram for an embarrassingly drawn "exploded" view of the plastic outlet box... (seriously, It's all I could do in paint. I tried...)

[image]

The "runs" are effectively Romex or whatever brand. Two incoming legs. The left "run 1" has 4 wires. Red, Black, White, and a bare copper. Oddly though... "run 2" only has 3 wires. I made very sure of this, but it's only black, white, and bare which is all twisted up with the bare from run 1. Nothing touches or connects to this bare ponytail.

**The objective!**

Replace the old single pole 2 wire fan toggle switch on the right side of the diagram.
The new Leviton smart switch will require a "black", a "red", and a "neutral" connection to work. This is the problem, I'm not sure where to get these from and I don't want to guess... because it seems like a real bad idea to guess with things like this.

Tools I have:
Basically everything for standard electrical work. Pliers, half jaws, stripper, electrical tape, Fluke volt/ohm meter, twist caps for binding wires, etc. I'm sure I have whatever I need - just not sure what to do here...

[Link to Leviton DZ15S product page](http://www.leviton.com/en/products/DZ15S-1BZ)

**Please help**!
and
**Thanks**!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this switch, black is *line*. That is the black wire coming in from the cable on the right to the black terminal block. Red is *load*. That is the other black wire on the old switch, which goes to the fan. Neutral is the white line coming in from the right.

Move the existing wires from the old switch over to the new switch. Add a white jumper (a short piece of wire, maybe 6") from the block terminal holding the other whites to the white terminal on the switch.

Comment: Attempting this now - thanks for the fast response. AFK while I give this a shot.

Comment: Please be sure to turn off the breaker before touching any wires. Confirm power is off with a non-contact tester or multimeter.

Comment: Absolutely - had to shutdown since I was killing the upstairs breaker. Back now that I'm re-energized. WORKED!! Sincere thanks! Awarding answer. Have a good one.